# What's the Ruby equivalent for Java's StringReader?

Tags: java, ruby

In Java, one can create an IO stream from a String like so:

```
Reader r = new StringReader("my text");
```

I'd like to be able to do the same in Ruby so I can take a string and treat it as an IO stream.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
r = StringIO.new("my text")
```

And [here's the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html).

Comment: One key thing that bit me (it's in the documentation; I just missed it) is that to get the result out you use #string, not #to_s. #to_s just tells you it's a StringIO. #string gives you the built result.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323/why-doesnt-ruby-have-a-real-stringbuffer-or-stringio

Comment: i'm using this to insert chart data from Gruff into a prawn PDF.