# Memory streams in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Does ruby have memory streams somewhere that I'm missing? It looks like IO is just for file-backed streams... I'm hoping for something similar to `System.IO.MemoryStream` in .NET?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323/why-doesnt-ruby-have-a-real-stringbuffer-or-stringio ?

Answer (score 8):

Are you after something like [StringIO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/classes/StringIO.html)?

Answer (score 6):

There are pipes:

```
r, w = IO.pipe
w.puts("Hello World")
puts r.gets
```

Comment: I think this is pretty much what I'm after...I don't really want text data only, and this looks like it's what I need! Thanks!